# ASP.NET Core efficient response stream content injection approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stream, middleware

I have a requirement to inject 'replacement' values into every HTML response that gets served by my app. These replacement values will be represented by string tokens, e.g:

```
[[Foo]]
```

Where this corresponds to a key in a lookup dictionary of values.

I need to do this in the most efficient way possible, avoiding extra `string` and `byte[]` allocations where possible.

I've written some middleware which uses a wrapped `Stream` to intercept the response write methods which then injects content at the location of one of these tokens.

Middleware `InvokeAsync`:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IResponseHelper responseHelper)
{
    if (!responseHelper.IsHtmlResponse())
    {
        await this.next(context);
    }

    using (var modifiedResponse = new ResponseWrapper(context.Response.Body, context))
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Body = modifiedResponse;

        await this.next(context);
    }
}
```

This just checks the content type to ensure its an HTML response and then passes the response to my wrapped stream.

Stream `WriteAsync`, crude example:

```
public override async ValueTask WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
     var arrayBuffer = buffer.ToArray();

     // Define the token and replacement bytes
     byte[] tokenBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("[[Foo]]");
     byte[] replaceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Some replacement value");

     // Get index of token in current buffer
     var index = arrayBuffer.AsSpan().IndexOf(tokenBytes);

     // If not found, write to next buffer
     if (index <= -1)
     {
         await this.stream.WriteAsync(arrayBuffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         return;
     }

     // Token found, write everything before the replacement
     await this.stream.WriteAsync(arrayBuffer, 0, index);

     // Then write the replacement
     await this.stream.WriteAsync(replaceBytes, 0, replaceBytes.Length);

     // Finally write the rest of the buffer, after the replacement
     int endIndex = index + tokenBytes.Length;
     await this.stream.WriteAsync(arrayBuffer, endIndex, buffer.Length - endIndex);
}
```

This is where I'm performing the replacements. I use `Span<byte>` to find the index of my token in the current buffer.

If not found, I write the buffer to the stream and wait for the next.

If it is found, I write everything before the token to the stream, then write the token replacement, then write everything after where the token would have been to the response.

This works well enough, but I have no control over how many of these tokens will be in the response, or whether they will inject duplicates.

In the case of duplicates, how can I handle this efficiently? Is there some way to bulk replace sequences of `byte[]` within another `byte[]`, all without allocating temp arrays etc...? Can this be made more efficient?

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I need to do this in the most efficient way possible`. Don't use C# . But seriously, that's quite a requirement you get there. Don't think you're young to achieve that. Because there's so many layers of optimization and effects can vary between platforms, any manual optimization would need to be carefully checked, benched and double checked in integration. Else is just cargo cult programming, where you generate a lot of unmaintainable code that isn't even that performant.

Comment: I also think you are skipping a number of steps in your explanation. You're already thinking on terms of _your_ solution and thus not properly explaining the original issue (which makes this kind of a XY problem). Maybe give some examples, including one that has the duplicate token issue. And a [mcve].

Comment: @JHBonarius which steps aren't clear? Perhaps I can clarify. The problem at a high level is quite simple and is already outlined in the question. I need to efficiently replace string tokens within a regular HTML response. The tokens can be added by website users so I have no control over the amount of times they show up, or whether they use duplicates. My solution above works fine assuming only a single instance per token, its when we need to consider duplicates that I'm concerned. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JHBonarius re; minimal complete example, this is about as minimal as it gets. I'd only be sharing the middleware scaffolding and the rest of the stream wrapper class which is irrelevant noise.

Comment: That's because you've probably been looking at this issue for many hours now. Take for instance where you write _"These replacement values will be small string tokens, e.g: [[Foo]]"_. Linguistically this would imply that you want you want to replace some unknown string with the string "[[Foo]]". I had to read the code to actually understand it's Foo you want to replace. What you wrote indeed works for a simple case, but isn't that efficient. A Token parser would be the way to go, as has been proven in many cases (compilers, (de)serializers, etc.).

Comment: Minimal examples also have unit tests. Our other demonstrating test cases. Anyhow, wanted to add to previous message: talking about optimization, async streams don't really add value here, as you're writing to a memory buffer. There's no slow IO or such. Dictionaries also aren't optimal for these situations. You need a per-character branching tree lookup.